# swiftyjson cannot convert rawstring back to a json object

Tags: swifty-json, rawstring

I have a json object like thies {"test" : "test"}, but if I convert it to a SwfiftyJSON.JSON object, and then I fetch the rawstring by function rawString(), then I convert the rawstring to a json object, but unfortunately, I can not get the correct json object, if I try to get "test" property or any other property, it always return nil, what is wrong?

Comment: What does the rawString() output look like?

Comment: like this: "{\n  \"Name\" : \"test planning line\"\n}", it contains line break

Answer (score 6):

**SWIFT 5**

If you want to get rid of white-spaces and new lines characters from your output, you should disable pretty Printing.

You can achieve this by

```
let myString = yourJsonObject.rawString(String.Encoding.utf8, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
```

Old versions

```
let myString = yourJsonObject.rawString(NSUTF8StringEncoding, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

Answer (score 3):

To update Tom's answer;

Swift 4 update:

```
let myString = yourJsonObject.rawString(String.Encoding.utf8, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))!
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 update:

`let myString = yourJsonObject.rawString(NSUTF8StringEncoding, options: [.jsonSerialization: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0)])`